# HTA Timer with MsgBox before time runs out?

Tags: vbscript, timer, hta

I used [this script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Accurate-HTA-Countdown-and-3fd670d6) to create a hta native countdown timer. I already modified the script to restart by pressing the Reset button.

But i'm wondering if it's possible to show a MsgBox let's say 5 minutes before the timer runs out? But the timer needs to keep running until it times out, and showing the last MsgBox.

Any help or suggestion are more than welcome

```
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Countdown Timer"
  BORDER="thin"
  MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  SCROLL="no"
  SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
  CONTEXTMENU="no"
  SELECTION="no"/>
</head>

<title>Countdown Timer</title>

<SCRIPT language="VBScript">

    Dim pbTimerID
    Dim pbHTML 
    Dim pbWaitTime
    Dim pbHeight
    Dim pbWidth
    Dim pbBorder
    Dim pbUnloadedColor
    Dim pbLoadedColor
    Dim pbStartTime

    Sub Window_OnLoad
        window.resizeTo 500,250 ' Width,Height      
        ' Progress Bar Settings
        pbWaitTime = 1200       ' How many seconds the progress bar lasts
        pbHeight = 30       ' Progress bar height
        pbWidth= 450        ' Progress bar width
        pbUnloadedColor="white"     ' Color of unloaded area
        pbLoadedColor="grey"        ' Color of loaded area
        pbBorder="black"        ' Color of Progress bar border  
        ' Don't edit these things
        pbStartTime = Now
        rProgressbar
        pbTimerID = window.setInterval("rProgressbar", 200)

    End Sub


    Sub rProgressbar
        pbHTML = ""
        pbSecsPassed = DateDiff("s",pbStartTime,Now)
        pbMinsToGo =  Int((pbWaitTime - pbSecsPassed) / 60)
        pbSecsToGo = Int((pbWaitTime - pbSecsPassed) - (pbMinsToGo * 60))
        if pbSecsToGo < 10 then
            pbSecsToGo = "0" & pbSecsToGo 
        end if
        pbLoadedWidth = (pbSecsPassed / pbWaittime) * pbWidth
        pbUnloadedWidth = pbWidth - pbLoadedWidth
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<table border=1 bordercolor=" & pbBorder & " cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=" & pbWidth & "><tr>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<th width=" & pbLoadedWidth & " height=" & pbHeight & "align=left bgcolor="  & pbLoadedColor & "></th>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<th width=" & pbUnloadedWidth & " height=" & pbHeight & "align=left bgcolor="  & pbUnLoadedColor & "></th>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "</tr></table><br>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=" & pbWidth & "><tr>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<td align=center width=" & pbWidth & "% height=" & pbHeight & ">" & pbMinsToGo & ":" & pbSecsToGo & " remaining</td>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "</tr></table>"
        progressbar.InnerHTML = pbHTML

        if DateDiff("s",pbStartTime,Now) >= pbWaitTime then 
        StopTimer 
        DoAction
        End if
    End Sub

    Sub StopTimer
        window.clearInterval(PBTimerID)
    End Sub

    Sub DoAction
        MsgBox "The Final Countdown"
    End Sub

    Sub ResetTimer
        Call Window_OnLoad
    End Sub

    Sub CancelAction
        On Error Resume Next
        Self.Close
    End Sub
</SCRIPT>

<body>
<div align="center">
Game countdown 20min<br><br>
<span id="progressbar"></span>
<br>
<input type="Button" value="Reset" onClick="ResetTimer" class="button"> <input type="Button" value="Close" onClick="CancelAction" class="button">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Using a standard `MsgBox()` will block execution so won't work but you could build a `<div>` and use that to show your message and the timer will still run.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try for this example instead of using a MsgBox you can use with a span tag for the warning message :

```
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Countdown Timer"
  BORDER="thin"
  MAXIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  MINIMIZEBUTTON="no"
  SCROLL="no"
  SINGLEINSTANCE="yes"
  CONTEXTMENU="no"
  SELECTION="no"/>
</head>

<title>Countdown Timer</title>

<SCRIPT language="VBScript">

    Dim pbTimerID
    Dim pbHTML 
    Dim pbWaitTime
    Dim pbHeight
    Dim pbWidth
    Dim pbBorder
    Dim pbUnloadedColor
    Dim pbLoadedColor
    Dim pbStartTime

    Sub Window_OnLoad
        window.resizeTo 500,250 ' Width,Height      
        ' Progress Bar Settings
        pbWaitTime = 1200       ' How many seconds the progress bar lasts
        pbHeight = 30       ' Progress bar height
        pbWidth= 450        ' Progress bar width
        pbUnloadedColor="white"     ' Color of unloaded area
        pbLoadedColor="grey"        ' Color of loaded area
        pbBorder="black"        ' Color of Progress bar border  
        ' Don't edit these things
        pbStartTime = Now
        rProgressbar
        pbTimerID = window.setInterval("rProgressbar", 200)

    End Sub


    Sub rProgressbar
        pbHTML = ""
        pbSecsPassed = DateDiff("s",pbStartTime,Now)
        pbMinsToGo =  Int((pbWaitTime - pbSecsPassed) / 60)
        pbSecsToGo = Int((pbWaitTime - pbSecsPassed) - (pbMinsToGo * 60))
        if pbSecsToGo < 10 then
            pbSecsToGo = "0" & pbSecsToGo 
        end if
        pbLoadedWidth = (pbSecsPassed / pbWaittime) * pbWidth
        pbUnloadedWidth = pbWidth - pbLoadedWidth
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<table border=1 bordercolor=" & pbBorder & " cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=" & pbWidth & "><tr>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<th width=" & pbLoadedWidth & " height=" & pbHeight & "align=left bgcolor="  & pbLoadedColor & "></th>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<th width=" & pbUnloadedWidth & " height=" & pbHeight & "align=left bgcolor="  & pbUnLoadedColor & "></th>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "</tr></table><br>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=" & pbWidth & "><tr>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "<td align=center width=" & pbWidth & "% height=" & pbHeight & ">" & pbMinsToGo & ":" & pbSecsToGo & " remaining</td>"
        pbHTML = pbHTML & "</tr></table>"
        progressbar.InnerHTML = pbHTML

        If DateDiff("s",pbStartTime,Now) = 5 Then
            Warning.InnerHTML = "<marquee  BEHAVIOR=""alternate"" BGCOLOR=""lime""><font face=""Comic sans MS"" color=""RED"" size=""3""><b>ATTENTION THIS IS A WARINING MESSAGE</b></font></marquee><br><br>"
        End If

        if DateDiff("s",pbStartTime,Now) >= pbWaitTime then 
        StopTimer 
        DoAction
        End if
    End Sub

    Sub StopTimer
        window.clearInterval(PBTimerID)
    End Sub

    Sub DoAction
        MsgBox "The Final Countdown"
    End Sub

    Sub ResetTimer
        Warning.InnerHTML=""
        Call Window_OnLoad
    End Sub

    Sub CancelAction
        On Error Resume Next
        Self.Close
    End Sub
</SCRIPT>

<body>
<div align="center">
Game countdown 20min<br><br>
<span id="progressbar"></span>
<span id="Warning"></span>
<input type="Button" value="Reset" onClick="ResetTimer" class="button"> <input type="Button" value="Close" onClick="CancelAction" class="button">
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by replacing this single If statement:

```
if DateDiff("s",pbStartTime,Now) >= pbWaitTime then 
StopTimer 
DoAction
End if
```

Into two seperate If statements:

```
    If DateDiff("s",pbStartTime,Now) = 900 Then
        AlmostTime
    End If

    If DateDiff("s",pbStartTime,Now) >= pbWaitTime Then
        StopTimer
        TimeUp
    End if
```

And created a new Sub called AlmostTime, which in turn shows a MsgBox or whatever I like.

Comment: That will still block execution while the `MsgBox()` is on the screen. You said in the question *"the timer needs to keep running until it times out"*, this solution does not do that. Like I said in the [above comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40742423/hta-timer-with-msgbox-before-time-runs-out#comment68711165_40742423) you'll need some custom message like a `<div>` that won't block the timer while it's displayed.

Comment: It did block it visually, but the timer kept running and when done the second MsgBox was show as well.
I replaced the MsgBox for a oShell.Run command in the final version.